# find an equilibrium position of thread

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions

There is a function $f(x)=1.5x^2-1.5x+\cos(3x)$. The thread moves along it. $x_1$ and $x_2$ are the beginning and end coordinates of this thread.

Is known that $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ and that thread length $=0.3$

How can I find $x_1$?  (It can be an approximation value.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is:

$\{x_1 = 0.784369, x_2 = 1.02514 \}$

Here is the function:

[image]

The path length is:

$$\int\limits_{x=x_1}^{x_2} \sqrt{1 + \left( \frac{dy}{dx} \right)^2}\ dx = \int\limits_{x = x_1}^{x_2} \sqrt{(-3 x+3 \sin (3 x)+1.5)^2+1}\ dx$$

and we want that to be $0.3$.

So here is a plot of that pathlength minus 0.3, with the contour of $0$ clear.  Our solution must lie somewhere along this boundary for the pathlength to be $0.3$.

[image]

We demand that $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$.  Here is a plot of the difference between those two:

[image]

Of course we get a zero when $x_1 = x_2$, but that is not what we want.

Here is a 3D plot of the sum of the absolute values of each of the above functions.  Our solution will occur when this sum is $0$ (both constraints satisfied):

[image]

A simple optimization routine call to minimize the sum of the absolute values of the above functions gives the numerical solution stated at the beginning of this answer, right at the unique minimum of the 3D graph.

Comment: Thank you! What did you use to make these plots? Could you send me a code of this solution?

Comment: Just deleted my *Mathematica* code.  You should write your own!

Comment: Ok:) Could you tell me the name of the function of the second plot?

Comment: `DensityPlot[]`.

Comment: Thanks again for helping